# Entity saved within @Transactional can't be found

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I've got problem with managing transactions using Spring. In single transaction I save two new entities and only one can be found.

Here's my method annotated with `@Transactional`

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public User createUser(CreateUserRequest request) {
    return userCreator.createUser(request);
}
```

and `createUser`:

```
User createUser(CreateUserRequest request) {
    // some validation and business processing
    User user = newUser(request);
    User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
    publishNewUserCreatedEvent(savedUser);
    return savedUser;
}
```

and `publishNewUserCreatedEvent`:

```
private void publishNewUserCreatedEvent(User user) {
    UserCreatedEvent event = new UserCreatedEvent(user);
    eventRepository.save(event);
}
```

Then I've got a worker thread that simply fetches the latest event from database and calls a handler for given event.
The problem is that for above example when the `UserCreatedEvent`'s handler is calling `UserRepository` for userId it got `EntityNotFound` exception. So the event was persisted, but the user wasn't (yet).
I've tried multiple things (like having two methods annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` where first one saves user to the repository so it should be commited first and the second saves event to the repository, I've tried with `TransactionTemplate`), but none has worked.

Most of the time retry works, meaning that executing the same event for the second time succeeds, so the user can be found. However it's annoying and I'd like to have control over transaction execution, so I'd expect that user will be saved before the event is saved, so when event handler loads event by ID and user by ID then both can be found.

Comment: have you tried `saveAndFlush` method?

Comment: You can enable show-sql=true and analyze the sql queries. It might give you some insight.

Comment: @kingGarfield yes, I've tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: @Shawrup indeed, forgot about this one. I'll try it